# Protecting my app from mocking the API response

Tags: android, rest

I have an android app which has some encrypted video files stored locally and only subscribed users will be able to decrypt it. I have a flag isScubscribed in my get user details API. Which will be set to true on sbubscription by paying money. What if some one spoof my get user API after intercepting and send another user details with the isSubscribed flag to true. Seems even API is protected over TLS this can be done. My app is meant to work offline and I am storing user details locally in android phone encrypted. So checking in server always is not an option.

Comment: "Seems even API is protected over TLS this can be done": why do you think this?

Comment: I thought from a browser client. When the underlying connection is from an untrusted server what we see is just the notation of unsafe in the browser, We have the option to proceed with exception. Seems the libray I am using in android [retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired) blocks this behavior by default. So app will not accept connections.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the http client I am using in my app [retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-trust-unsafe-ssl-certificates-self-signed-expired) blocks untrusted connections. So unless my application is re-engineered to tweak the behavior my app is secure. Comments are welcome if anyone has any different opinion.